# Using Impact analysis in Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

I tried using `frama-c-gui` and was able to perform impact analysis
But I am not able to figure out how can we pass statment number on which the impact analysis needs to be performed in batch mode of Frama-C.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special annotation `//@ impact pragma stmt;` that you can use to indicate that you are interested in the impact of the statement following the annotation. Then, if said annotation is in function `f`, you can use the following command line to print the impacted code on the command line:

```
frama-c -impact-pragma f -impact-slicing impact.c -then-on "impact slicing" -print
```

- `-impact-pragma f` indicates that you are interested by the statements flagged by a pragma in function `f`
- `-impact-slicing` indicates that you want to create a project named `impact slicing` containing the statements impacted by the one(s) you have selected.
- `-then-on "impact-slicing"` let you continue the analysis on project `impact slicing` (here we only `-print` the code, but you can put any option you like after `-then-on project_name`)

Note however that the `impact` plugin is quite experimental.

Comment: Thanks it helps. But its only performing the intra-procedure impact analysis , is there any options available for inter-procedure analysis for the impact plugin which can help us to provide the exact line number in source code for which we want to do the impact analysis? 
And also is it possible to get the source code line numbers of the impacted statments ?

Comment: As far as I know, impact is inter-procedural by default. Option `-impact-not-in-callers` will prevent the analysis in callers, but is not activated by default.

Comment: In addition, if you want to print the location of the impacted statement, you'll have to write a small script that does that. Using a visitor on the `impact slicing` project and `Cil_datatype.Stmt.loc` function, this should not be too difficult. See Frama-C's developer manual (http://frama-c.com/download/plugin-development-guide-Neon-20140301.pdf) for more information about Frama-C's scripts.